# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) While Installing mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, debian

I am trying to install `mysql-server-5.5` by `apt-get install mysql-server-5.5` and I see this error - `Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server
```

Output of `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
  tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.5
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1981 kB of archives.
After this operation, 32.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 95180 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 5.6 to 5.5.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.5, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Mint. Which distro are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  I had a 10.1 flag with Mint.
Find out what flag you have using:

```
sudo ls -al /var/lib/mysql/
```

Then remove the file 
`sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/debian-5.6-flag`
Then try to reinstall
`sudo apt-get -f install`

Hope that works for you

see this [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/618358/how-to-deal-with-a-package-failing-to-be-configured-properly-due-to-its-init-scr) article, might be more relevant to your specific errors

Comment: I did all that long ago, but `mysql` doesn't start. It says `start: Job failed to start`

Tried everything but no luck :(

Comment: are you still getting the same error when you try to sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: also have you fixed the locale warning?  I ended up updating dpkg.